# Fundamental Verilog Concepts

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have my first verilog assignment due in a few days and for whatever reason these concepts are escaping me. I don't think I'm thinking in terms of parallelism and hardware or something.

My question is that I have to `and` a few switches and buttons together using `wire`s and turn on 3 LEDs in array of 7. I'm pretty sure I know how to do the computational logic, but I can't figure out how to use `assign` and `wire` to properly turn on all 3 LEDs without writing 3 separate lines. It feels wrong to do:

```
assign Led[0] = output;
assign Led[1] = output;
assign Led[2] = output;
```

Also, it's weird because there are 7 LEDs on the board and I'm picking on LEDs 0,2,4.

Can someone walk me through how this is supposed to work the *proper* way? We don't have a textbook and I've been reading the basics online, but I just can't seem to figure out how this is supposed to work. Thanks!

Edit: This is my current code, but I am getting errors that say nothing is "driven". What gives?

```
module Lab2_1(input [5:0] sw, input btns, output [7:0] Led );

    wire [2:0] leds; 
    wand out; 

    assign leds = {Led[0], Led[2], Led[4]};

    and U1   (out, sw[0], sw[1]);
    and U2   (out,~sw[2],~sw[3]);
    xor U3   (out,sw[4],sw[5]);
    assign   out = btns;
    assign leds[2:0] = {3{out}};

endmodule
```

Errors:

```
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<3>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<4>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<5>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<6>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<7>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<0>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<1>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <Led<2>_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   is not driven by any source pin in the design.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<3>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<4>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<5>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<6>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<7>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<0>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<1>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <Led<2>_OBUF> is completely unrouted.
ERROR:Bitgen:25 - DRC detected 16 errors and 0 warnings.  Please see the
   previously displayed individual error or warning messages for more details.
```

Comment: Within the Lab2_1 module, you are not assigning the 8-bit `Led` output.  Note that `assign` statements are uni-directional, from right-hand side to left-hand side.  So the line `assign leds = {Led[0], Led[2], Led[4]};` means you are "reading" the output, which may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have already seems perfectly fine, though if you wanted to do it in one line you could use a concatenation and or replication operators to assign multiple bits of `Led`. Both these statements are equivalent to your code sample:

`assign Led[2:0] = {output, output, output};`

or

`assign Led[2:0] = {3{output}};`

I don't know if these are any better or more proper than what you already have, but just writing them to show some examples of what is possible to do.

=== EDIT ===

You're getting errors because you're not driving any of the bits of `Led`.

1. This looks backward: `assign leds = {Led[0], Led[2], Led[4]};` 
   `Led` is the **output** of the module, so it should be assigned to, meaning it should be on the left hand side of the equal, so I would guess this should look like `assign {Led[0], Led[2], Led[4]} = leds;`
2. Your module has an 8-bit Led output, but you're only assigning 3 bits of it. You should assign the other 5 bits to either constant 1 or 0.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. I didn't know you could do that. However, I'm still getting errors. I've updated the original question with my new issues. Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, I was thinking about this all wrong. Thanks for clarifying; hopefully now I can do the rest of this without issues. You don't know how much I appreciate it! THANKS!